# Flutter Image Crop Not Responding

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-image

I am trying to crop an image from picked image from gallery, the image is picked perfectly but while trying to crop an image it seems nothing happened in the screen, and some problem detected in console though I can't understand the problem. the code I have used is from official pub.dev site [https://pub.dev/packages/image_cropper/example]

My Task is : pick and crop an image for

Help me to Resolve this Problem, Thanks in Advance.

The Code:

....

```
class _EditGalleryScreenState extends State<EditGalleryScreen> {  
  File imageFile;
  List _galleries = new List();

  @override
  void initState() {
    .....
  }

  ....
  //SOME API CALLS

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Gallery"),
      ),
      body: _galleries.isNotEmpty
          ? GridView.builder(/* DIAPLYING LIST OF IMAGES FROM API CALL */)
          : SizedBox(),

          //BUTTON TO TRIGGER IMAGE PICKER
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        tooltip: "Add Image",
        onPressed: () {
          _pickImage();
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.add_a_photo),
        backgroundColor: AppColors.PRIMARY_COLOR,
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<Null> _pickImage() async {
    // imageFile = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery); // this was deprecated so i have updated to otherone

    PickedFile imageFile = await ImagePicker().getImage(
        source: ImageSource.gallery,
        maxWidth: 500,
        maxHeight: 500,
        imageQuality: 20);

    if (imageFile != null) {
      setState(() {
        state = AppState.picked;
        debugPrint("Image Picked and State Changed");
        _cropImage();//calling CROP FUNCTION
      });
    }
  }

  Future<Null> _cropImage() async {
    debugPrint("Crop Image Called");
    File croppedFile = await ImageCropper.cropImage(
        sourcePath: imageFile.path,
        aspectRatioPresets: Platform.isAndroid
            ? [
                CropAspectRatioPreset.square,
                CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio3x2,
                CropAspectRatioPreset.original,
                CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio4x3,
                CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio16x9
              ]
            : [
                CropAspectRatioPreset.original,
                CropAspectRatioPreset.square,
                CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio3x2,
                CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio4x3,
                CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio5x3,
                CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio5x4,
                CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio7x5,
                CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio16x9
              ],
        androidUiSettings: AndroidUiSettings(
            toolbarTitle: 'Cropper',
            toolbarColor: Colors.deepOrange,
            toolbarWidgetColor: Colors.white,
            initAspectRatio: CropAspectRatioPreset.original,
            lockAspectRatio: false),
        iosUiSettings: IOSUiSettings(
          title: 'Cropper',
        ));
    if (croppedFile != null) {
      imageFile = croppedFile;
      setState(() {
        state = AppState.cropped;
      });
    }
  }
}
```

[Screen Shot of Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rc1mV.png)

Comment: did you setUp in manifest file as per documentation ?

Comment: not yet, you mean android_manifest.xml right? can text what should i update?

Comment: now i have updated in xml file and tried again, same result

Comment: yes it works after changing xml file, and cleaning the old files using flutter clean

Comment: Great.........:)